# Очистить кэш Redis программно

Tags: c#, asp.net, кэширование, redis

В своём приложении я использую Redis в качестве кэш-хранилища, куда в процессе работы заносятся разные данные. Некоторые хранятся там временно (минут 5), некоторые без ограничения по времени.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
    {                
        option.Configuration = Configuration["Redis:Address"];
        option.InstanceName = "...";
    });  
}
```

Также у меня есть метод, вызываемый при закрытии приложения

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
    ...
}

private void OnShutdown()
{
    ...       
}
```

Каким образом я могу достать в методе `OnShutdow` кэш-хранилище и полностью очистить его, чтобы при следующем запуске приложения данных о его предыдущей работе не было?

Comment: Экземпляр IDistributedCache приходит в зависимости? Пробовали Remove на нем вызвать? Или привести к IDisposable и вызвать Dispose?

Comment: @АндрейNOP `IDistributedCache` имеет метод удаления лишь по ключу`void Remove(string key);` , а мне нужно очистить вообще всё. Насчёт зависимости: метод `OnShutdown` располагается в классе `Startup`, через конструктор я не могу его получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из возможных решений ( и видимо единственное ) - выполнение операции через командную строку

```
    private void OnShutdown()
    {
        if(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            ExecuteCommand("redis-cli flushall");     
        ...       
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
        Console.Write("Execution result: ");
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```